# How do I get result from treasure data query into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, treasure-data

I have some trouble loading result of query in treasure data to pandas dataframe. What I tried so far:

```
import pytd.pandas_td as td
engine = td.create_engine('presto:dbname')

df = td.read_td(['SELECT * FROM shop_items'], engine, index_col='time', parse_dates=None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-d7c67d01919b> in <module>
----> 1 df = td.read_td(['SELECT * FROM shop_items'], engine, index_col='time', parse_dates=None)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytd\pandas_td\__init__.py in read_td_query(query, engine, index_col, parse_dates, distributed_join, params)
    190 
    191     return _to_dataframe(
--> 192         engine.execute(header + query, **params), index_col, parse_dates
    193     )
    194 

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Other thing i have tried was

```
df = td.read_td('SELECT * FROM shop_items', engine, index_col='time', parse_dates=None)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-87be9bfcb398> in <module>
----> 1 df = td.read_td('SELECT * FROM shop_items', engine, index_col='time', parse_dates=None)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytd\pandas_td\__init__.py in read_td_query(query, engine, index_col, parse_dates, distributed_join, params)
    190 
    191     return _to_dataframe(
--> 192         engine.execute(header + query, **params), index_col, parse_dates
    193     )
    194 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytd\pandas_td\__init__.py in _to_dataframe(dic, index_col, parse_dates)
    326 
    327 def _to_dataframe(dic, index_col, parse_dates):
--> 328     frame = pd.DataFrame(**dic)
    329     if parse_dates is not None:
    330         frame = _parse_dates(frame, parse_dates)

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I have tried to use 'pytd.pandas_td Reference' but repeating steps listed there was not successful.

Comment: Are you sure that the first argument should be the query string in a list, and not just the query string?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I tried 

'df = td.read_td('SELECT * FROM shop_items', engine, index_col='time', parse_dates=None)'

which returned TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: nah, got  TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Then please add this to your question.